# ERROR: admin.E108 and admin.E116 Django Framework Python

Tags: python, html, django, django-admin, blogs

I got the these two errors below:

> <class 'blog.admin.CommentAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of
> 'list_display[4]' refers to 'active', which is not a callable, an
> attribute of 'CommentAdmin', or an attribute or method on
> 'blog.Comment'.

> <class 'blog.admin.CommentAdmin'>: (admin.E116) The value of
> 'list_filter[0]' refers to 'active', which does not refer to a Field.

This is my models.py code:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

STATUS = (
   (0,"Draft"),
   (1,"Publish")
)

class Post(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
   slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
   author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE,related_name='blog_posts')
   updatedOn = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)
   content = models.TextField()
   createdOn = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)

   class Meta:
       ordering = ['-createdOn']

   def __str__(self):
       return self.title


class Comment(models.Model):
   post = models.ForeignKey(
       Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
   name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
   email = models.EmailField()
   body = models.TextField()
   createdOn = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   
   class Meta:
       ordering = ['createdOn']

   def __str__(self):
       return 'Comment {} by {}'.format(self.body, self.name)
```

This is my admin.py code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post, Comment

# Register your models here.

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'slug', 'status','createdOn')
    list_filter = ("status", 'createdOn')
    search_fields = ['title', 'content']
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}

@admin.register(Comment)
class CommentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'body', 'post', 'createdOn', 'active')
    list_filter = ('active', 'createdOn')
    search_fields = ('name', 'email', 'body')
    actions = ['approveComments']

    def approveComments(self, request, queryset):
        queryset.update(active=True)


admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

This is my forms.py code:

```
from .models import Comment
from django import forms


class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('name', 'email', 'body')
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
```

should be:

```
active = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The message is clear 'active' is not a field

```py
class Comment(models.Model):
   post = models.ForeignKey(
       Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
   name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
   email = models.EmailField()
   body = models.TextField()
   createdOn = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

your fields are: post, name, email, createdOn, status

Therefore create a field named active or suppress active in `list_display` &
`list_filter`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> ERRORS: <class 'store.admin.PersonAdmin'>: (admin.E116) The value of
> 'list_filter[0]' refers to 'PersonAgeFilter', which does not refer to
> a Field.

When assigning **the custom filter `PersonAgeFilter`** to [list_filter()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter) with parentheses as shown below:

```py
# "store/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

class PersonAgeFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    # ...    

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ("PersonAgeFilter",)
                 # ↑  Parentheses  ↑
```

So, I removed the parentheses from `"PersonAgeFilter"` as shown below then the error was solved.

```py
# "store/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

class PersonAgeFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    # ...    

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = (PersonAgeFilter,) 
                 # Without parentheses
```